# cronologでphp_error_logを分割するには

Tags: php, linux, centos, apache

cronologを使い php_error_logが分割できなくて困っています。

下記のようにhttpd.confを書いてしてErrorLogやCustomLogはcronologで正常にログ分割ができています

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   370592  1月 26 23:42 access_log.2015.01.26
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     4680  1月 27 10:14 access_log.2015.01.27
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   233081  1月 26 19:35 error_log.2015.01.26
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      148  1月 27 09:12 error_log.2015.01.27
```

が、httpd.confの

```
php_value error_log "|/usr/sbin/cronolog /home/htdocs/logs/php_error_log.%Y.%m.%d"
```

の部分がうまく動きません。logsフォルダ内にファイル自体が作られません。

ただし、

```
php_value error_log "/home/htdocs/logs/php_error_log"
```

のようなcronologを使わない分割なしのphp_error_log出力はできますのでlogsフォルダのパーミッションやphp.iniの設定は問題ないと思っています。
/home/htdocs/logsのパーミッションはapache:apacheです。

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 apache apache 4096  1月 27 09:12 logs
```

---

### httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost xxxxxxxxxxx.jp:80>
DocumentRoot "/home/htdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
ServerName xxxxxxxxxxxxx.jp:80
ServerAlias www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jp
ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/cronolog /home/htdocs/logs/error_log.%Y.%m.%d"
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/cronolog /home/htdocs/logs/access_log.%Y.%m.%d" combined

<Directory "/home/htdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
    php_value error_log "|/usr/sbin/cronolog /home/htdocs/logs/php_error_log.%Y.%m.%d"
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP のエラーログは下記のようなパイプの指定はできません。

```
php_value error_log "|/usr/sbin/cronolog /home/htdocs/logs/php_error_log.%Y.%m.%d"
```

この記述は Apache の設定ファイルの中で PHP の設定を記述しているだけなので、Apache の ErrorLog や CustomLog でパイプが使える、というのと、PHP の error_log でパイプが使えるかどうかは別です。

php のエラーログは logrotate などでローテートするか、error_log の設定を syslog するなどの別の方法が必要です。

あるいは error_log を未設定にしておけば Apache のエラーログに PHP のエラーログも出力されるようになるので、Apache の ErrorLog ディレクティブで cronolog を利用することは可能です。

Comment: なるほど、やはりphp_value error_logは、ErrorLogやCustomLogとはしくみが違うのですね。
やりかたとしては
１）分割しないでphp_error_log一本で出力して他の方法でローテート
２）logrotateやsyslogなどcronolog以外の手法を取る
３）cronologを使うがphp_error_logを分離しないでerror_logの中に混ぜて出す。
ですね。３）は既にできていますので、１）と２）を試してみます。
ありがとうございました。すっきりしました。